# Cannot find the file in the system

Tags: python

```
import pandas
import xlwings as xw
A = pandas.read_excel('Thali Details.xls', sheet_name='A')
sheet = xw.Book(r'D:\Taha\Python\Test Codes\Thali Details.xls').sheets("A")
count = 2
count = count + 1
cell = "D" + str(count)
Scan = input('ID:')
RFID_A = A['RFID']
list_A = list(RFID_A)
Status = A['Status']
for x, y in zip(RFID_A, Status):
if int(Scan) == x:
    while int(Scan) == x:
        if y == 'Start':
            print('Thali scanned successfully')
            sheet.range(x).value = "tick"
            break
        else:
            print('Thali Stop')
            break
else:
    while int(Scan) != x:
        for x, y, in zip(RFID_A, Status, ):
            if int(Scan) == x:
                if y == 'Start':
                    print('Thali scanned successfully')
                    break
                else:
                    print('Thali Stop')
                    break


Scan = input('ID: ')
```

And I get this error "pywintypes.com_error: (-2147024894, 'The system cannot find the file specified.', None, None)" what am i supposed to do as i have even provided the path

Comment: Can you share the full traceback?

Comment: Why there is 2 different path in your code? `'D:\Taha\Python\Test Codes\Thali Details.xls'` and `Thali Details.xls`. maybe this is the source of the problem. try to replace `Thali Details.xls` with `r'D:\Taha\Python\Test Codes\Thali Details.xls'`

Comment: i tried doing it with both types of path

Comment: they both are same just tried to see if it makes diffrence

Answer (score 0):

The file is not found, as it states. 
Open CMD and command `IF EXIST "D:\Taha\Python\Test Codes\Thali Details.xls" ECHO File exists.` and if it outputs `File exists` then please update the question and let us know.